# Computer inoperational but motherboard LED on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

My friend's computer switched off suddenly and since then nothing happens when you press the power button - no spinup, fans or anything. The only sign of life is that the motherboard LED is on. Is this a motherboard or a PSU issue? We can't find any blown capacitors.

Comment: The model of motherboard would be helpful. Is the light labeled? Some boards have lights to indicate that there's *any* power, some have lights that indicate there's *good* power.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell without testing. Short the trigger pins on the PSU to see if it starts up, and try a fresh PSU with the motherboard as well.